# What does Http Debugger do with http requests?

Tags: http, proxy, fiddler

My program sends http requests to `https://auth.riotgames.com/api/v1/authorization` server. As I understand it, cloudflare is installed there, which blocks my requests by issuing a 403 status code.
But the problem is that if I run the Http Debugger (https://www.httpdebugger.com/) the server responds fine. This is independent of the use of a proxy. Might have something to do with the certificates as I tried to connect with Fiddler installed on another machine (with Http Debugger running on my machine) and if Fiddler decrypts the http traffic it starts responding with 403, and if it doesn't decrypt it responds fine.

With Http Debugger:
[image: With Http Debugger]

With Http Debugger and Fiddler on another machine:
[image: With Http Debugger and Fiddler on another machine]

If it's not clear, ask questions. I will be glad to any suggestions, for me it is very important.

Comment: From your links it looks like you're sending different data. I don't know riotgames' API but I doubt it would accept the data in your second link. It's also possible that Cloudflare specifically blacklists Fiddler. You should try other (non-auth) requests and to test this.

Comment: The two posted requests are different, that could be the cause for the HTTP 403.